# Cannot get info from error when trying to get JSON data via JQuery,

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api

For the life of me i can't figure out why i keep getting an error when making an AJAX request using the bit of bode below.  When the page load, and the alerts pop up absolutely no useful information as to why the request failed, the response code is 200 in firebug, readyState, and status are both 0 when the pop up, and responseText is empty.  I can access the request using the browser just fine.  I just goes to the error callback function:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    function loadData(url, container) {
        var data =[];

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data,container);
                alert(container);   
            },
            error: function(xhr,err) {
                alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);

            }
        });
    };

    loadData( 'http://api.giantbomb.com/genres/?api_key=####&format=json', '#genres-pane');

});


</script>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean "getting an error"?

Comment: as i said above, the ajax code goes to the error callback, despite a 200 response code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do a cross-domain request as JSON, which means using XmlHttpRequest in the backend.  This is disallowed due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  Try changing your data type to "jsonp".  You'll also need to change your url's `format` argument from "json" to "jsonp".

Comment: used $.getJSON instead of $.ajax as it seems to handle jsonp requests more elegantly.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

FireBug for firefox will show you all requests, posts, responses, etc. Very useful for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Yes, for some reason in Firebug i get a 200 response code on the request, but during the jquery ajax request, the error callback get thrown.